# Does logback need groovy.jar or groovy-all.jar?

Tags: groovy, logback, logback-groovy

I'm looking to minimize the size of my software distribution, and `groovy-all.jar` is by far the biggest JAR. Groovy is used for logback configuration[1]. On the bottom of the [Groovy download page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download) there's a section on the split Groovy distribution.

Which modules / JAR files does logback need to function properly? Is just `groovy.jar` sufficient?

[1] Yes, I realize I could configure logback with XML, eliminating the need for Groovy support. That is not my question.

Comment: It should be sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'd rather not run into obscure problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a source, but as of logback version 1.0.13 my tests show that groovy-jsr223 is needed as well. If I import only groovy in my pom.xml, logback complains about missing classes. The error message is

`ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Groovy classes are not available on the class path. ABORTING INITIALIZATION.`

My dependency configuration that works is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.13</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-jsr223</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not working with Logback anymore so I can't verify your answer. But it looks good so I'll mark it as accepted.